# Adding texture to object

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to import an object with a obj. file. The shape comes in but it doesn't have any texture. This is the first time I'm trying this.

Is the coding correct?

```
from object:
mtllib Mandark.mtl

o Inst3D_RefRep.558

v 0.011818 1.659554 -0.150772

vt 0.080000 0.221000

usemtl RefRep.558_Body.png_Body.png

s 1

f 1/1 2/2 3/3

f 3/3 2/2 4/4

f 1218/900 1216/897 1217/895

o Inst3D_RefRep.558_Ref

v -0.153880 2.519897 0.040634

v -0.150564 2.538620 0.018198

vt 0.823000 0.878000

vt 0.823000 0.986000

usemtl RefRep.632_Body.png_Body.png

s 1
f 1298/966 1299/967 1300/968

f 1298/966 1300/968 1301/969



From mtl.:

newmtl RefRep.632_Body.png_Body.png

Ns 90.196078

Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

Kd 0.409600 0.409600 0.409600

Ks 0.125000 0.125000 0.125000

Ni 1.000000

d 0.000000

illum 2

map_Kd Texture\Body.png

newmtl RefRep.558_Body.png_Body.png

Ns 92.156863

Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

Kd 0.512000 0.512000 0.512000

Ks 0.250000 0.250000 0.250000

Ni 1.000000

d 0.000000

illum 2

map_Kd Texture\Body.png
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no texture on the object? Are you viewing it in solid view, material preview, or render view? The default is solid view, which in turn by default will not show textures even if they are set up completely properly. To learn more about the subject, visit the blender manual at docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html

Comment: Also, you seem to be asking about the syntax of the OBJ file. If you wrote that yourself, well done, because that’s good stuff to know, but it isn’t strictly Blender related.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  This question is getting close votes because it lacks details or clarity.  You can edit your post to include more details, or in this case a screenshot might be helpful, and it will be automatically queued for review to be reopened.

Comment: Make sure the texture is in the same folder as the blend file in a folder named Texture